# Baffled by the outcome of If, continue, and else in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, continue

here is the offending piece of code:

```
data = requests.get(searchURL, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config.flxusername, config.flxpassword), verify=False)
feed_data = data.content
d = feedparser.parse(feed_data)

tickets=[]
for ticketNum in d['entries'] :
    tickets.append(ticketNum['title'])


s = requests.Session()
s.get(ticketsBaseUrl, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config.flxusername, config.flxpassword), verify=False)


for ticket in tickets :

    ticket_page = s.get(ticketsBaseUrl+ticket, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config.flxusername, config.flxpassword), verify=False )

    if ticket_page.status_code == 404 :
        print('ticket %s data 404, skipping' %ticket)
        continue
```

Now this piece of code by itself results in the expected 3 skips for the 404 response.

However, when I add an else:

```
data = requests.get(searchURL, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config.flxusername, 

config.flxpassword), verify=False)
feed_data = data.content
d = feedparser.parse(feed_data)

tickets=[]
for ticketNum in d['entries'] :
    tickets.append(ticketNum['title'])


s = requests.Session()
s.get(ticketsBaseUrl, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config.flxusername, config.flxpassword), verify=False)


for ticket in tickets :

    ticket_page = s.get(ticketsBaseUrl+ticket, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config.flxusername, config.flxpassword), verify=False )

    if ticket_page.status_code == 404 :
        print('ticket %s data 404, skipping' %ticket)
        continue
    else :
        etree = ET.fromstring(ticket_page.content)
        print(etree)
```

The last 404 page content is passed to etree and the script errors out.

When I just do an else: print(ticket_page.status_code) it prints 3 error messages and the rest it prints 200.  It only starts trying to parse the final 404 when I put in the etree piece.  It is maddening.

What am I missing here?

Tried another alternative:

```
data = requests.get(searchURL, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config.flxusername, config.flxpassword), verify=False)
feed_data = data.content
d = feedparser.parse(feed_data)

tickets=[]
for ticketNum in d['entries'] :
    tickets.append(ticketNum['title'])


s = requests.Session()
s.get(ticketsBaseUrl, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config.flxusername, config.flxpassword), verify=False)


for ticket in tickets :

    ticket_page = s.get(ticketsBaseUrl+ticket, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config.flxusername, config.flxpassword), verify=False )

    if ticket_page.status_code == 404 :
        print('ticket %s data 404, skipping' %ticket)
        continue

    etree = ET.fromstring(ticket_page.content)
```

this also doesn't skip the last 404.

tested a smaller code section:

```
if ticket_page.status_code == 404 :
    print(str(ticket_page.status_code) + ' ' + ticket)
    continue
else :
    print(ET.fromstring(ticket_page.content))
```

fails; tried to fromstring the last 404 in the list.

```
if ticket_page.status_code == 404 :
    print(str(ticket_page.status_code) + ' ' + ticket)
    continue
else :
    print('continued')
```

works, prints the 3 404's and prints continued for everything else. (which is not technically correct; it actually processed everything else)

Tried it the opposite way:

```
if ticket_page.status_code == 200:
    print(ET.fromstring(ticket_page.content))
else :
    print(str(ticket_page.status_code) + ' ' + ticket)
    continue

if ticket_page.status_code != 200:
    print(str(ticket_page.status_code) + ' ' + ticket)
    continue
else :        
    print(ET.fromstring(ticket_page.content))


if ticket_page.status_code != 200:
    print(str(ticket_page.status_code) + ' ' + ticket)
    continue

print(ET.fromstring(ticket_page.content))
```

same results. still fails on the final 404

even

```
for ticket in tickets :

    ticket_page = s.get(ticketsBaseUrl+ticket, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config.flxusername, config.flxpassword), verify=False )

    if ticket_page.status_code != 200:
        tickets.pop()
```

leaves a 404 in the list.

This is the XML that is throwing the parse error:

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>\n\n<error><statusCode>404</statusCode><name>Not Found</name><description>The server has not found anything matching the request URI: Ticket not found</description></error>\n\n'
```

Latest test:

```
if 'statusCode' in tree_root.decode() : 
    print(ticket)
    continue
```

this gives me the 3 expected tickets.

```
if 'statusCode' in tree_root.decode() : 
    print(ticket)
    continue
etree = ET.fromstring(ticket_page.content.decode())    
print(etree)
```

this fails on the 3rd 404 ticket.  Adding a delay, thinking that this was happening because of a ton of 200 before the final 404, didn't change the outcome.

Comment: Please recheck/fix the displayed indentation. The first code block is definitely wrong (would raise a `SyntaxError`), and the indentation on the `else` in the second block is *really* important; if it's wrong even a little, by accident, the code does completely different things.

Comment: hello, could you please share an example of whats in the tickets list? and which 3 error messages you get?

Comment: the tickets are just a list that contains GUIDs to pass to the ticketsbaseURL like 00000e03-c06e-4417-985b-0437bc40b5d7 which either returns a 200 and some XML content or a 404 and  something that looks like XML, but isn't recognized as XML by the library.  So I am trying to skip attempting to read the 404 pages at all.

Comment: ah yea, I see what happened on the indent, let me fix that; it is right in my script.

Comment: Haramoz the 3 404's when I issue the simple print if 404 are:

404 00000e03-c06e-4417-985b-1faae4955e13
404 0000179c-2efc-4001-8bd8-0437bc40b5d7
404 00005ee2-6984-400a-9a19-5bd0eb2f46e3

when I put anything else after the IF it tries to process the last one.

Comment: in the list of 25, the 404's happen at index 2,4,15.  So it's not the first two or the last one.

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 19, column 0

It's a parse error on the XML; the only difference I can find in the XML returned between a 404 and a 200 is that the 404 is not UTF8. I posted the XML for the 404.  That is why I am trying to skip the 404 pages so I can skip the parse error.  If I can get it to parse the xml no matter what and discard the error XML I am all for that.

Comment: The only logical conclusion is that you have a URL that is returning a status code of 200 but text that belongs to a 404. Try running your test with the single failing URL and print both the status code and the text.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but why would it print a status code 404 and show a 404 when I load it in a browser; when it hits that loop with something other than a print statement it suddenly changes doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as follows:

Check all your 200's; it wasn't a 404 that was causing the issue.  One of the 200's has bad XML.  Most of the variants I posted would and do work just fine.  I was spot checking my 200's and every spot check I was missing the one with the bad XML.  I figured out how to handle the bad XML and was able to complete.